# Building a perfect binary tree with height 30

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to build a perfect binary tree with a height of 30. It doesn't have to be a BST, just a regular tree; The data isn't important either, so each node's data can be null. I've never tried to do anything like this before, so I was a little dismayed when my approach to creating this tree resulted in insane memory usage and started locking up my computer after running for a few minutes. Here's my Python code for building the tree:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = val

def build_tree(h):
    node = Node(0)
    if h == 1:
        return node
    node.left = build_tree(h-1)
    node.right = build_tree(h-1)
    return node

root = build_tree(30)
```

It's probably worth mentioning that I did try using a list representation as well. Unfortunately, the memory usage of a list that size is problematic too.

Can anyone shed any light on a method of accomplishing this that doesn't use so much memory and could be accomplished in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Wow... do you know how many nodes there are in a tree of height 30?

Comment: I wonder if you were supposed to create a tree with 31 nodes. That would be a much more reasonable request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a perfect binary tree, the number of nodes in each level doubles. The number of nodes total in a binary tree with `n` levels is `2**n-1`. That means a perfect binary tree with 30 levels will have

> 1,073,741,823

nodes. This will result in "insane memory usage" unless you repeat nodes, which is out for a "perfect binary tree."

The best you can do is to use the smallest amount of memory possible for each node. The best I can think is to use the list representation of a complete binary tree--the children of the node at index `j` are at indices `2*j` and `2*j+1` and the parent node is at index `j//2`. (This is for a one-based array.) This means you do not need to store pointers or indices to child or parent nodes. Finally, use a list that takes as little memory as possible. T[Numpy's Boolean array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)uses only one byte per item. This still means a gigabyte of memory for your tree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This confirms my suspicions and makes me think the height I was given might have been a mistake.